# How can I get value in [Object]

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, coinmarketcap

I'm working on coinmarketcap.com api and I need only name and price and save to Mongo. It is working but at the end undefined value returned. Price value is under the quote. What is wrong ?

```
const axios = require('axios');
let response = null;
new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
  try {
    response = await axios.get('https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest?limit=2', {
      headers: {
        'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': 'myKey',
      },
    });
  } catch(ex) {
    response = null;
    console.log(ex);
    reject(ex);
  }
  if (response) {
  const coin = response.data;
  console.dir(coin, { depth: null }); 
  console.log(coin.data.map(a => { a.name,  a.quote.price}));
    resolve(coin);
  }
}
);
```

Comment: Can you provide the "object" too?

Comment: if thats your real api key. you better not post it here

Comment: I'm pretty sure `new Promise(async (` is pointless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`quote` contains prices identified by their keys like this:

```
"quote": {
                "USD": {
                    "price": 42177.91536878145,
                    "volume_24h": 18068350418.6717,
                    "volume_change_24h": 8.1323,
                    "percent_change_1h": -0.02144759,
                    "percent_change_24h": -0.48235688,
                    "percent_change_7d": -0.65364542,
                    "percent_change_30d": -1.87762517,
                    "percent_change_60d": -13.80076009,
                    "percent_change_90d": -30.24448455,
                    "market_cap": 799599134284.9932,
                    "market_cap_dominance": 42.7605,
                    "fully_diluted_market_cap": 885736222744.41,
                    "last_updated": "2022-02-14T09:35:00.000Z"
                }
            }
```

so in order to solve the bug, you need to specify the proper key here (USD for example):

I tested this code and it works please copy it inside the separate js file and check the result(Replace  your API key):

```js
const axios = require('axios');
let response = null;
async function getCoin(){
  try {
    const response = await axios.get('https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest?limit=2', {
      headers: {
        'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': 'KEY',
      },
    });
    const coin = response.data;
    const result = coin.data.map(a => ({ name: a.name,  price: a.quote['USD'].price}))
    console.log(result)
    return coin;
  } catch(ex) {
    console.log(ex);
    throw ex;
  }
}
getCoin()
```

Comment: I did but still same. Original output like this
 data: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Bitcoin',
      ..
      quote: {
        USD: {
          price: 42084.21125563891,
          ..
        }
      }
    },

Comment: have you returned the map data?

Comment: resolve(coin.data.map(a => { a.name,  a.quote['USD'].price})

Comment: @genzowakabayashi

Comment: yes i did. i see undefined output

Comment: I've tested and updated my answer please copy it inside a separate js file and run it, don't forget to replace your API key

Comment: Glad that it works, could you please accept my answer?

Comment: Of course, last thing, I will save results to database like an array results[0],[1] etc. Is there any practical way or is this okey ?

Comment: I think the better approach would be to use json/jsonb database schema and then store them exactly like it is, it's much easier to read and retrieve them later:
for MySQL => https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html
for postgres => https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-json.html

Answer (score 2):

You shuldn't be wrapping this in another `Promise` (see: [What is the explicit promise construction antipattern and how do I avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it)) , just make a method which is async

```
async function getCoin(){
  try {
    const response = await axios.get('https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest?limit=2', {
      headers: {
        'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': 'YOURKEY',
      },
    });
    const coin = response.data;
    console.dir(coin, { depth: null }); 
    return coin;
  } catch(ex) {
    console.log(ex);
    throw ex;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const axios = require("axios");

async function fetchData() {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(
      "https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest?limit=2",
      {
        headers: {
          "X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY": "myKey",
        },
      }
    );

    return [response, null];
  } catch (error) {
    return [null, error];
  }
}


// in your calling function code base
const [response,error] = await fetchData()

if(response){
    // handle response object in calling code base
    const coin = response.data
}

if(error){
    // handle error explictly in calling code base 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting price in quote.USD or quote['USD'] and also need to return object of name and price using map.

So Try this:

```
const axios = require('axios');
let response = null;
new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
        response = await axios.get('https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest?limit=2', {
            headers: {
                'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': '5345bcb4-0203-4374-bef6-d67a89a6d216',
            },
        });
        if (response) {
            const coin = response.data;
            cointData = coin.data.map(a => ({ name: a.name,  price: a.quote.USD.price }))
            resolve(cointData);
        }
    } catch (ex) {
        response = null;
        console.log(ex);
        reject(ex);
    }
});
```